# Injecting .net MVC application as micro front end using single spa

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have a .net MVC application running in `https://localhost:7166/` I have another application in `Angular` which is running in `http://localhost:9002/`. I'm trying to bring these together as a `microfrontend` using `single-spa`.

I have a base application where all the applications are imported.

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@single-spa/welcome": "https://unpkg.com/single-spa-welcome/dist/single-spa-welcome.js",
        "@angular-app/angular-project": "http://localhost:9002/main.js",
        "@dotnet/home":"http://localhost:7166/"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <% } %>
```

**Routes**

```
<single-spa-router>
  <main>
    <route default>
      <application name="@dotnet/home"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="flights-search">
      <application name="@angular-flightBooking/angular-flightbooking"></application>
    </route>
  </main>
</single-spa-router>
```

The angular application is working fine, but the dotnet app returns `CORS` issue in browser. Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

A .Net MVC web application cannot be used as microservice with `single-spa`.  `single-spa` only works with JavaScript frameworks, and this is something a .Net MVC web application is **not**.